# Despite using token_provider, the REMEMBERME cookie is still sent

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

According to [Storing Remember Me Tokens in the Database](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#storing-remember-me-tokens-in-the-database), I can store the (hashed) contents of a `REMEMBERME` cookie in the database for added security. I followed every step in that section, so my config now looks like this:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    …
    Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\RememberMe\DoctrineTokenProvider: ~
```

```yaml
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            user:
                …
                schema_filter: ~^(?!rememberme_token)~
```

```yaml
# config/security.yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            …
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 2592000
                token_provider: 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\RememberMe\DoctrineTokenProvider'
```

and I created the corresponding table `rememberme_token` in the database.

After logging in, I can see the token being stored in the database, but I still get a `REMEMBERME` cookie sent to the browser. How can I prevent this?